# Reading values from config file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

I am working in linux and have a config file with a lot of single lines formatted like this:

```
Variable1=Value1
Variable2=Value2
Variable3=Value3
```

I need something I can run on command line that will echo the value for the respective variable. I have been playing with sed all day, but having a heck of a time. I'm not sure if that's even the best way. Any help would be super.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat a.sh
Variable1=Value1
Variable2=Value2
Variable3=Value3 

$ source a.sh
$ echo "$Variable1"
Value1
```

Note, `source` will overwrite the value of `Variable1` for the current shell.

Comment: Dangerous if you don't trust your values, of course.

Comment: simplest use source file is `. a.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Search for the variable name and the equal sign, remove them, and print the result.

```
$ sed -n '/^Variable1=/{s/^Variable1=//;p}' config.txt
Value1
```

Comment: This would typically be simplified to `sed -n '/^Variable1=/s///p'`